Case condition for each rows with same ID but different status
I'm trying to write a case condition but not getting expected results.
Query:
select case when subject='maths' and subject='PCM' then 'Science_student'
       case when subject='biology' and subject='arts' then 'Non-Pcm' end student_type
from students
`



Data looks like:

Studentid subject       date_added
12184      maths         15mar2024 
12184      arts          15mar2024
12184      PCM           14mar2024   
12185      accounts      11aug2024    
12185      arts          10aug2024  
12198      biology       17aug2024
12198      arts          16aug2024 `

So If the student id's status is "Maths" and "PCM" then it should be labelled as "Science_student"
and if status is "biology" and "arts" then it should be labelled as "Non-Pcm"
Expected Output:
Studentid subject     date_added Student_type
12184      maths      15mar2024   Science_student
12184      arts       15mar2024   null
12184      PCM        14mar2024   Science_student  
12185      accounts   11aug2024   null   
12185      arts       10aug2024   null
12198      biology    17aug2024   Non-pcm
12198      arts       16aug2024   Non-pcm

Problem in my query is that it is checking for the status in same rows .
let me know how can i do this
`

@JonasMetzler,I have updated the data, yes all rows with a matching status should be updated with 'Science_student'

@JonasMetzler  , Apologies My bad , I had given the wrong data(data updated ) .Yes you are right 17aug one also be labelled as Non-pcm .Thank you for your time.

@JonasMetzler, Yes it supports CTE's.

If you want to stick to your case whens, here is a possible solution. Since I have no experience with google-bigquery here is a Postgresql solution. Digging into bigqueries - documentation: array_agg exists, I don't know about the any - Syntax to search an array.
https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler#?id=32960553-4d79-4d65-a296-9669deb0e9c9
with data as (select studentid, array_agg(subject) as subjects from students group by studentid)
select 
students.*,
case 
    when 'maths'=any(subjects) and 'PCM'=any(subjects) then 'Science_student' 
    when 'biology'=any(subjects) and 'arts'=any(subjects) then 'Non-Pcm' 
end student_type
from students inner join data on students.studentid = data.studentid 

So in the CTE there are arrays of all subjects collected for each student and within the case when construct those arrays are search by any(subject).
However, are you sure about your testdata. Shouldn't the student type be equal for each student id, e.g. in every line for student id 12184 should be Science_student.

Not working ,any function not supported in bigquery

So at last after commentless downvoting a helping comment. Thx. So this any - part should be replaced by something like "2=(select count(*) from unnest(subjects) as subj where subj in (...)".
